# How to change camera angle of StreetViewPanoramaFragment?

Tags: android, google-street-view

```
StreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewFragment = (StreetViewPanoramaFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.g_map_street);
streetViewFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(this);

@Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {
        streetView = streetViewPanorama;
        streetViewPanorama.setPosition(new LatLng(Latitude, Longtitude));
    }
```

I have a value of **Heading** which returns angle.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=800x800&location=%s,%s&heading=%s

Using it , I can get Streetview Image properly but not working in **StreetViewPanoramaFragment**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally** , after lots of R&D I found this solution.. and its works for me.

```
@Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {
    streetViewPanorama.setPosition(new LatLng(Latitude, Longtitude));
    try {
        //Change angle of street view
        final int DURATION = 1000;
        StreetViewPanoramaCamera camera = new StreetViewPanoramaCamera.Builder()
                .zoom(streetViewPanorama.getPanoramaCamera().zoom)
                .tilt(streetViewPanorama.getPanoramaCamera().tilt)
                .bearing(streetViewPanorama.getPanoramaCamera().bearing + angle) // angle value by Maps Api
                .build();
        streetViewPanorama.animateTo(camera, DURATION);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```